# SQLAlchemy session after exception

Tags: python, session, exception, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, after an exception, the session needs to be set again because of the rollback. Should I therefor always set the session between calls?

```
user = User('username', 'Full Name', 'password', 'email',
                datetime.now(), 'username')
session.add(user)
try:
    session.commit()
except SQLAlchemyError:
    pprint('Not quite right...')

# the session needs to be re-instantiated in case of an exception.
# should I always do it or only if there was an exception above?
session = Session()
res = session.query(User).all()
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish:

```
try:
    session.commit()
except SQLAlchemyError:
    pprint('Not quite right...')
    session.rollback()
```

[Fishing rod](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html).